# How do I close an open socket on app exit

Tags: python, kivy

I am starting out with learning to build `server client apps` and found a nice [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739907/how-connect-my-kivy-client-to-a-server-tcp-sockets) My ultimate goal is to transfer files from server to clients and plot the received data on the app.

I have built up on an example app here. Could someone suggest how to call the `close socket` function when exiting from the app?

I am assuming one needs to close the socket only on program `exit` and not after each file transfer. Hence I put the code to close the socket right at the end.

I thought of using `on_stop` in the `ClientAPP` class. But since the variables haven't been created yet, referencing the function from there doesn't seem possible.

I am following the suggestions from one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850261/doing-something-before-program-exit) :

server.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
from threading import Thread

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Creates socket object
        self.serversocket = socket.socket()

        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = 54545

    #If we had used s.bind(('localhost', 80)) or s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80)) we would still have a �server� socket, but one that was only visible within the same machine. s.bind(('', 80)) specifies that the socket is reachable by any address the machine happens to have.

    def start_server(self):
        self.serversocket.bind(('', self.port))

        self.serversocket.listen(10)

        self.clientsocket, self.addr = self.serversocket.accept()
        print("got a connection from %s" % str(self.addr))

        confirmation = 'Connected'
        self.clientsocket.send(confirmation.encode())

        #start_listening
        Thread(target=self.print_received_client_data).start()

    def print_received_client_data(self):
        while True:
            print('Received from client: %s' % self.clientsocket.recv(1024).decode())        

if __name__=="__main__":
    Server().start_server()
```

ClientAPP.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from threading import Thread
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import socket, time
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sock_instance = MySocket()
        Thread(target=self.set_text_input).start()

    host = "localhost"
    port = 7000
    display = ObjectProperty()

    def set_text_input(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.text = self.sock_instance.get_data()                  

    def send_message(self):  
        #self.ids.display.text is encoded and sent            
        self.sock_instance.sock.send(self.ids.display.text.encode()) 

    def receive_message(self):
        # Decodes a reply, Converts it to a str, prints it           
        print("Message from server - %s" % str(self.sock_instance.sock.recv(1024).decode("ascii")))

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MySocket:

    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=54545):

        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        #Receives confirmation from Server, Converts to string, Prints confirmation
        print("%s" % str(self.sock.recv(1024).decode()))         

    def get_data(self):
        return self.sock.recv(1024)

    def close_socket(self):
        self.sock.close()

class ClientAPP(App):

    def build(self):
        runtime_instance = ScreenManagement()
        return runtime_instance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_instance = ClientAPP()
    try:
        app_instance.run()
    finally:
        #Code to close socket here, ideally, call close_socket
        print("Closed the socket")
```

ClientAPP.kv

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<ScreenManagement>:
    transition:FadeTransition()
    HomeScreen:
    SettingsScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.2,0.2
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.4}
            text: "Send Message"
            on_press: root.send_message()
        TextInput:
            id: display
            size_hint: 0.2,0.2
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.4}
            text: "abc"
```

Edit - Incorrect server.py posted earlier

Comment: By the time that you get to the finally statement your server thread and associated objects will be dead so you won't have access to the socket.  You have to do it before the background thread terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

### Close Socket - when window is closed i.e. click on X

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.core.window import Window`
2. Add `Window.bind(on_request_close=self.close_socket)` into `__init__()` method of class `MySocket:`.

### Close Socket - when exit app

1. In kv files, add `id: home_screen`
2. In Python files, add `on_stop()` event and invoke `close_socket()` method, into class `ServerApp()` and `ClientApp()`.

## kv files - add *id*

### server.kv & client.kv

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    HomeScreen:
        id: home_screen
        name: 'home_screen'
    SettingsScreen:
        name: 'settings_screen'
```

## Python files

### server.py

```
class MySocket:

    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=54545):
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.close_socket)

    ...

    def close_socket(self, *largs, **kwargs):
        print("\nServerApp.close_socket:")
        print("\tClosed the socket")
        self.sock.close()


class ServerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.runtime_instance = ScreenManagement()
        return self.runtime_instance

    def on_stop(self):
        print('\nServerApp.on_stop:')
        self.runtime_instance.ids.home_screen.sock_instance.close_socket()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerApp().run()
```

### main.py

```
class MySocket:

    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=54545):
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.close_socket)

    ...

    def close_socket(self, *largs, **kwargs):
        print("\nClientApp.close_socket:")
        print("\tClosed the socket")
        self.sock.close()

class ClientApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.runtime_instance = ScreenManagement()
        return self.runtime_instance

    def on_stop(self):
        print('\nClientApp.on_stop:')
        self.runtime_instance.ids.home_screen.sock_instance.close_socket()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

## Output

### ServerApp sends data

[image: Img01 - ServerApp send data]

### ClientApp received data

[image: Img02 - ClientApp received data]

### ServerApp exit

[image: Img02 - ServerApp exit]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the nice answer :) Assign an ID and call thus call the function.

I posted the wrong server.py by mistake. I implemented your suggestions to the ClientAPP.py.  Using window worked. The socket is being closed on shutdown now.

Add "from kivy.core.window import Window" as well. For anyone else reading the post. 

Im having a new problem now. When I close the client app, and try to open it again, the ClientAPP hangs. Presumably it cannot connect to the server again. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Put the statement, waiting for connection i.e. `self.clientsocket, self.addr = self.serversocket.accept()` in a loop before receiving / sending data (nested loops).

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you